# How to read the same number in a column and consider it In or Out

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

See the image above. In this image, I want the content in column B to be generated using a formula. Let me explain what is happening.

If a fruit's name is read for the first time, then it is "1", the second time "0", and anymore than two times, there is something wrong, or an "Error". Apple is an example of that. Similarly, I want this done for all the fruits.

Comment: Expand on "read". Read by what?

Answer (score 2):

In cell B1 and copied down, use this formula:

```
=INDEX({1,0,"Error"},MIN(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1),3))
```

Comment: You have a great ability to think outside the box.  I was working on a nested if, but this is perfect.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you!  I'm still trying to figure out the `AGGREGATE` function though, your use of it is astounding :)

Comment: @tigeravatar Thanks a lot!